# What is the best way the get the most accurate time Python?

Tags: windows, time, ntp

I have 2 laptops and this code:

```
import time

print(time.strftime('%H %M %S'))
```

But it seems like there is a slightly delay for about 3 seconds even i turned on 'Set time automatically' (Windows 10) and i have no idea about that. Because of that on each laptop it prints different time. Are there any ways to get the most accurate time?
Laptop 1:

```
11 22 36
```

Laptop 2:

```
11 22 33
```

Comment: Are the clocks of these laptops synchronized ?

Comment: _delay for about 3 seconds_ What do you mean by "delay"?  The python script pauses for three seconds before printing the time?  Or do you just mean it's three seconds behind your wristwatch?

Comment: @John Gordon: Laptop 2 is 3 seconds behind laptop 1

Comment: @alfasin Yes all synchronized with time.windows.com

Comment: Do you have some other way of verifying that the two clocks are identical?  Like opening the system clock display on both laptops and visually comparing them?  I guarantee you python isn't causing this.

Comment: But I didn't ask if they're sync'ed with *another* computer, I asked if they are synced between themselves. When one of them changes the minute - does the other do it exactly at the same time?

Comment: @John Gordon: I've already done that, one is 3 seconds behind the other. I can't find any solutions for this. Are there any other ways on python to solve this issue?

Comment: maybe [this](https://superuser.com/q/425233/501265) could be of some help? John is right though, this is not related to python in any way.

Comment: There is no easy way to sync between two computers. Best way is to use `ntp` protocol and sync time with time.windows.com

Comment: @djinn windows doesn't specifically support ntp, but rather uses it's own special sauce rolled from the same specifications: [w32tm](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/939322/support-boundary-to-configure-the-windows-time-service-for-high-accura)

Comment: My bad. I did not know, windows does not support `ntp`.

Comment: Based on some very quick research, when you check the box to synchronize time with time.windows.com, it doesn't necessarily happen right away.  It might wait a day, or two, or up to a week to actually synchronize.

Comment: @John Gordon: But the problem is i checked that box 2 months ago on both laptops, still one is 3 seconds behind the other.

Comment: Once the clock is synchronized, that doesn't mean the time will be perfectly accurate forever.  Most PC clocks will naturally gain or lose a few seconds every week.

Comment: In the date and time control panel app, you can configure internet time updates to use use any NTP server (of course Windows supports NTP; not having a command named `ntp` is irrelevant). For convenience, the drop-down box is populated with time.windows.com and time.nist.gov. There's also an "update now" button. From the command line, use [w32tm.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799054), e.g. `w32tm /resync`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've found the answer. I went into time.is, timeanddate.com, ... and saw that those time are almost the same. So i can use selenium to get the time from time.is and work on that.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://time.is')

def main():
    hm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="twd"]').text
    sec = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leaps"]').text
    print('%s:%s'%(hm,sec))
main()
```